# Symfony2 - Sonata Admin. Show color table in field form entity

Tags: forms, symfony, colors, field, sonata-admin

I'm using Sonata Admin to administrate some of my entites on my web application. One of them is 'accessLevel'. One of its fields is 'color' that is a VARCHAR(6) on my MYSQL database and I use on the 'style= background-color: #{{ color }}' tag on its TWIG.
I would like, if it were possible, to show a color table when I create or edit my 'accessLevel' entity to choose one and store its hexadecimal value on the database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you please elaborate the question please, and what exactly is needed

Answer (score 2):

in the master version of sonata core bundle i found [this](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-color-picker)

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'SonataCoreBundle:Form:colorpicker.html.twig'
```

and the  configureFormFields will be like this :

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('color', 'sonata_type_color_selector')
        // ...
    ;
}
```

I hope that help !

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [Genemu JQueryColor Field](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/color/index.md)

```
<?php
// ...
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('color', 'genemu_jquerycolor')
        ->add('colorpicker', 'genemu_jquerycolor', array(
            'widget' => 'image'
    ))
}
```

I use this bundle with SonataAdmin, and everything works fine.

Have a look at [the doc](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/README.md) to see what you can do with this bundle.

Don't forget to **update your template** to add javascript and css files. See [this link](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/template.md)

Hope this is what you want

Comment: One question: what kind of field types do you use in your Entity for storing color values? I have color, which is type string, and then I must have colorpicker too, otherwise it complains that there is no method for property colorpicker. Can you please edit your answer to show part of entity file? And also where do you include javascript and css files. Is this standard_layout.html.twig (sonata admin)?

Comment: @repincln Kinda late, but `genemu_jquerycolor` has `text` as `parent`, see: https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Form/JQuery/Type/ColorType.php